# Using recursive hierarchy SSAS Cube in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, ssrs-2012, ssas-2012

I am trying to create an SSRS report from an SSAS cube with the following format

[image]

So what I did is create a database table with recursive hierarchy which we can call here a location dimension (dimLocation) and it has the following layout

[image]

Then under SSAS multidimensional model, I have created a self-joined Dimension which generates the following hierarchy

- Americas

  - USA
- Europe

  - France

    - Paris
    - Marseille
  - Germany
- Africa

Next, I created the SSAS cube using my fact table and the self-joined dimension, deployed it and tried to use it in SSRS, but I was not able to create the layout above.

What I have tried so far, is to create a Tablix with a group on columns, set the group properties to group on [Parent_ID.UniqueName] and recursive parent on [Parent_ID.ParentUniqueName]. It almost worked fine except that the groups are being expended horizontally and not vertically as my expected layout.

[image]

I am starting this project from scratch, which means I am free to change the table structures etc… Is it possible to achieve such layout with my actual cube/dimensions? Or maybe I should redesign my dimension source table and create another type of hierarchy than a recursive one?

Comment: Please share the result of the query you are using in Tablix dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your dataset is generated so I guessed a possible query result

[image]

Then created a dataset that generates the above results and added a Matrix with the following arrangement.

[image]

You should get the following matrix

[image]

Maybe this can help you to change your cube structure. I don't think recursive hierarchies can be useful in a cube, taking in account that cube calculations are based on a bunch of joins between dimensions.

Post your query and explain how quantity is related with the recursive hierarchy table for our understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually this is an imaginary scenario, my real data are different but the idea is the same, the data set is similar to the one I have in the second screenshot , it is a Dimension table with recursive hierarchy, and the Quantity is from a Fact table with a foreign key to the dimension table, I have succeeded to generate the same layout with a differrent Dimension (non recursive) but that would mean if I have a new level I will need to add it as column to the dimension

Comment: Maybe you can generate those columns logically from recursive hierarchy dimension creating query members but It could imply a complex MDX script. Also you can query the underlyng relational DB where you can do this smoothly just for this report.